# Woocommerce php array select dropdown only shows 10 results

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this product dropdown for Woocommerce.

**Problem is: it does only display 10 product..
I would like it to show all of my products!**

Can anyone guide me to the problem :-) ?

Dropdown:

```
         <option value=""> - Select poster - </option>';
                            
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
                $loop->the_post();
                $post_id = $loop->post->ID;
                $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
                $image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
                $title = $product->get_name();
                $permalink = $product->get_permalink();
                echo '<option value="'.$image_url.'" producturl="'.$permalink.'".>'.$title.'</option>';
            endwhile;
    
            // Reset post data
            wp_reset_postdata();
    
    
    echo'</select>
```

Note: A jQuery scripts sorts the dropdown alphabetically, and another script makes next and previous buttons for the dropdown - but i guess thats not the problem..

Answer (score 0):

solved: just WP settings -> max post pr page was set to 10